# Sub Query Count

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to `JOIN` 2 tables to count ethnicity based on 1st table `(student_schedule)`,
where student may show up more than 1 time. Table 2 `(bday)` just has the student show up 1 `time by ID` with the `student's ethnicity`. I am using a `LEFT JOIN` because on occasion I may have a missing student in the bday table and they will not be counted (since their ethnicity was not declared).

```
 SELECT bday.Ethnicity, ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID)/(SELECT  
 COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID) FROM student_schedule
 WHERE student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%')*100,2) AS "% of AS Population",  
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID) FROM student_schedule AS 
 "Total Student Population") 
 FROM student_schedule LEFT JOIN bday ON student_schedule.ID=bday.ID WHERE    
 student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%' GROUP BY bday.Ethnicity
 ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID) DESC
```

The result is 3 columns (Ethnicity, % of AS Population, Total Student Population). 
[image]

In order to compare percentage of students with Course `Like 'AS%'`,
I would like to add another column that gives me the ethnicity for the whole school Grouped by Ethnicity. In other words, 32% of White students took AS versus the White population of the school is 30%. The data is comes from table 2 (bday), which lists every student with their ethnicity. It should be something like

```
SELECT COUNT(bday.Ethnicity) 
FROM student_schedule
LEFT JOIN bday ON student_schedule.ID=bday.ID.
```

I'm stuck with the `GROUP function` needed for `COUNT` to separate into categories `(White, Black,...).`

Ideally, my result would be...

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
 //NOTE: I AM USING PDO FOR SIMPLICITY... BUT ANY OTHER DBAL WORKS AS WELL... 
//DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
defined("HOST")     or define("HOST",   "localhost");           //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-HOST
defined("DBASE")    or define("DBASE",  "_TEST_");              //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
defined("USER")     or define("USER",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
defined("PASS")     or define("PASS",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS



try {
    $dbh            = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $sql            = 'SELECT COUNT(SS.ID) AS "Global_Student_Population" FROM student_schedule AS SS ';
    $stmt           = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result         = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    $intAllStudents = (int)$result[0];

    $sql            = " SELECT BD.Ethnicity, {$intAllStudents}  AS Global_Student_Population,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT SS.ID) AS Ethnic_Student_Population,
                        ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT SS.ID)*100/{$intAllStudents}) AS '%_of_AS_Population'
                        FROM student_schedule AS SS
                        LEFT JOIN bday AS BD ON SS.ID=BD.ID
                        WHERE SS.Course LIKE 'AS%' GROUP BY BD.Ethnicity";

    $stmt           = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result         = $stmt->fetchAll();

      var_dump($result);
      var_dump($intAllStudents);

    //GARBAGE COLLECTION
    $dbh        = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My var_dump() displays something like this:

```
        array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=8)
          'Ethnicity' => string 'Black' (length=5)
          0 => string 'Black' (length=5)
          'Global_Student_Population' => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => string '10' (length=2)
          'Ethnic_Student_Population' => string '3' (length=1)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
          '%_of_AS_Population' => string '30' (length=2)
          3 => string '30' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=8)
          'Ethnicity' => string 'Hispanic' (length=8)
          0 => string 'Hispanic' (length=8)
          'Global_Student_Population' => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => string '10' (length=2)
          'Ethnic_Student_Population' => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
          '%_of_AS_Population' => string '10' (length=2)
          3 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=8)
          'Ethnicity' => string 'White' (length=5)
          0 => string 'White' (length=5)
          'Global_Student_Population' => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => string '10' (length=2)
          'Ethnic_Student_Population' => string '2' (length=1)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
          '%_of_AS_Population' => string '20' (length=2)
          3 => string '20' (length=2)
```

And here is my TEST Table Definitions:
        --
        -- Table structure for table `bday`
        --

```
    CREATE TABLE `bday` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Ethnicity` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `bday`
    --

    INSERT INTO `bday` (`ID`, `Ethnicity`) VALUES
    (1, 'Black'),
    (2, 'Black'),
    (3, 'Black'),
    (4, 'White'),
    (5, 'Hispanic'),
    (6, 'White'),
    (7, 'Asian'),
    (8, 'Hispanic'),
    (9, 'White'),
    (10, 'Black');

    --
    -- Indexes for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- Indexes for table `bday`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `bday`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `bday`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `bday`
      MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;




    --
    -- Table structure for table `student_schedule`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `student_schedule` (
    `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `Course` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `student_schedule`
    --

    INSERT INTO `student_schedule` (`ID`, `Course`) VALUES
    (1, 'AS'),
    (2, 'AS'),
    (3, 'EN'),
    (4, 'EN'),
    (5, 'AS'),
    (6, 'AS'),
    (7, 'EN'),
    (8, 'EN'),
    (9, 'AS'),
    (10, 'AS');

    --
    -- Indexes for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- Indexes for table `student_schedule`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `student_schedule`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `student_schedule`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `student_schedule`
      MODIFY `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SQL` is a little bit messy, Lets first re-construct it to make it more clear and readable :

```sql
SELECT bday.Ethnicity
        , ROUND(
            COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM student_schedule
                                                WHERE Course LIKE 'AS%')
            *100,2) AS "% of AS Population"
FROM bday INNER JOIN student_schedule on bday.ID=student_schedule.ID
WHERE student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%'
GROUP BY bday.Ethnicity
```

Notice here I used `INNER JOIN` as it's better here, if there were some students with no `Ethnicity` declared you will get their percentage which makes sense (and can be filtered out in the`WHERE`clause)

Now we want to add the `(count)` of the students of each `Ethnicity` from the table `bday`, to do that we simply add a `Sub-Query` to the `SELECT` list :

```sql
SELECT bday.Ethnicity
        , ROUND(
            COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM student_schedule
                                                WHERE Course LIKE 'AS%')
            *100,2) AS "% of AS Population"

        , ROUND(
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bday a WHERE a.Ethnicity=bday.Ethnicity)
            /(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bday)
            *100,2) AS "Ethnicity of School"        
FROM bday INNER JOIN student_schedule on bday.ID=student_schedule.ID
WHERE student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%'
GROUP BY bday.Ethnicity
```

Note here I set an `alias` of the sub-query's table `bday` as `a` to avoid conflicting with the outer `bday` table when using it in the `WHERE` clause inside the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to start from the beginning when you are hung up. I decided to start with the global COUNTS and then use CASE statements to do the WHERE counts. I finally got it to work the way I needed.The solution I came up with is:

```
SELECT bday.Ethnicity, ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%' THEN student_schedule.ID END)/(SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID) FROM student_schedule WHERE 
student_schedule.Course LIKE 'AS%')*100,2) AS '% of AS Population', 
ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
student_schedule.ID) FROM student_schedule)*100,2) AS '% of Student 
Population'
FROM student_schedule INNER JOIN bday ON student_schedule.ID=bday.ID
GROUP BY bday.Ethnicity
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT student_schedule.ID) DESC
```

Result is:
[image]